# Сolor css как сделать?

Tags: css3

Как сделать равномерное наложения цвета на картинку?

Comment: Какого цвета, на какую картинку? Что значит равномерное? А наложение?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @vp_arth, он видать background-blend-mode имеет ввиду...

Answer (score 5):

```css
#div1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: url('https://get.wallhere.com/photo/temple-sunset-city-cityscape-reflection-sky-skyline-skyscraper-evening-morning-tower-France-Paris-Eiffel-Tower-dusk-spire-tree-landmark-186143.jpg'), red;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<p>пример background-blend-mode</p>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

```css
#div2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: url('https://get.wallhere.com/photo/temple-sunset-city-cityscape-reflection-sky-skyline-skyscraper-evening-morning-tower-France-Paris-Eiffel-Tower-dusk-spire-tree-landmark-186143.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#div2::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: orange;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<p> пример c opacity и псевдоэлементом ::after</p>

<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: А не лучше добавить :before с opacity? Больше гибкости, шире поддержка браузерами.

Comment: @Telion, предлагаю запостить отдельным ответом.